# Use powershell variable to execute a program at the filepath in the variable

Tags: powershell, variables, filepath

I want to store an absolute file path in a power shell variable and use it to execute a program with arguments. I want to do this on a build server so I can have a utility on that build server used by build agents. Consider this:

```
$pathToExe = "C:\path\to\program.exe"

#build server does stuff in a working dir

$pathToExe arg1 arg2
```

When this runs, $pathToExe does not expand to its value. Instead, I see in the logs: "Unexpected token 'arg1' in expression or statement."

What's the proper way to do this kind of thing in power shell? I've tried other syntax with quotes but I can't get it to work without hardcoding the file path, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I think you will need to use `Start-Process`

Comment: How so? Like this?

Start-Process $pathToExe arg1 arg2

Comment: Here is an example of one I use currently. I hardcoded my arguments but variables can be used. `Start-Process -FilePath ($Firefox + "Firefox_62.exe") -ArgumentList ("-ms /INI=$Firefox" + "Firefox_Settings.ini") -Verbose -Wait -NoNewWindow`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use call operator `&`. See examples below:

```
$executable = 'notepad.exe'
$argument = 'E:\Temp\Test.xml'

& $executable $argument
& $executable 'E:\Temp\Test.xml'
```

See `Get-Help about_Operators` or this [MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#special-operators).

Comment: I did not know about this method. I like it. https://ss64.com/ps/call.html for further information. Thanks @Pawel Dyl

Comment: The `call` operator is also called the `invocation` operator.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly when I had $executable = "C:\path\program.exe".